# alert($('.class').length); throws error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Usually .length should return 0 or greater,

I don't understand why, but:

```
alert($('.class').length);
```

Is throwing, i can see in google chrome's console, this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null test-shop.mysite.com/store/es/:1102
(anonymous function)
```

Any idea why could this be?

Comment: are you sure `$` is jquery?

Comment: Have you added reference to JQuery script

Comment: are you sure `.class` exists ?!

Comment: what is your HTML? can you create a fiddle?

Comment: yes, and if in console i execute: '$().jquery' it returns 1.6.2

Comment: @NikhilPatel it still should return 0.

Comment: it's difficult to tell without some sort of an example or reference, but double check that **$** jquery reference refers to the jQuery function. Try ```alert(jQuery('.class').length)``` and see if that throws an error.

Comment: when is `alert` called relative to when jquery is loaded?

Comment: Is it throwing exception when you wrap it up into `$(function(){ ... })`

Comment: @Satpal if he didn't then he should get "ReferenceError: $ is not defined", so the most probable possibility is `$` being overwritten by another function.

Comment: following @DanielA.White's questions - are you sure **$** is jQuery *at the line where your alert statement is being called?*

Comment: If **eventually** $ refers to jQuery, this still doesn't eliminate the possibility that another library hijacks the global $ variable at the moment of your execution. try ```console.log($.fn.jquery)``` right before your alert.

Comment: Maybe you have another framework on the page as well and don't use the jQuery no conflict mode.

Comment: $ had been renamed to $j... >.<  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I seem to be able to replicate the same error message is when `$` is reassigned to a null returning function. For example:

```
$ = function(){ return null; };
alert($('.class').length);
```

In order to fix the issue, you need to find out where the code is that is reassigning `$`

The following may be able to help you debug the issue:

```
alert($);
```

Hopefully you can use that to identify what `$` actually is at the time of calling

Comment: that was it, i figured it out but took me a while... it had been renamed to $j... thanks!